# Latching push switch without a programmable IC

Tags: switches, attiny

Is it possible to make a push switch latching without using a programmable IC?

I have a circuit with a 555 chip creating a square wave. I would like to add a push switch which when pressed once will turn the circuit on, then when pressed again will turn the circuit off.

Is it possible to do this without using a programmable IC? I was thinking of using an ATTINY85 but was wondering if there is an easier and more cost effective way.

Comment: If you use a micro like an ATtiny you can do away with the 555 and have the micro do both the latching and generate the square wave.

Comment: How about a mechanical pushbutton switch that does exactly that? A "maintained' pushbutton switch - they are very common.  Push once to turn on, push again to turn off.

Comment: Another 555 could be used. There's a actual latch inside...

Comment: @GodJihyo Great point. I hadn't thought about it in that way. I was hoping to keep the circuit as cheap and simple and possible and feel I am over reliant on programming IC's rather than using analog circuitry. I wanted to ensure I was doing it the most efficient way and not using unneeded IC's. But this may very well be the most efficient way

Comment: Circuit as cheap as possible = one MCU to do everything.

Comment: @winny Interesting. I am very new to electronics - would you say that this is a principle I should stick to for all future circuit design

Comment: Yes. MCUs are getting cheaper and cheaper while ever so more versatile. Your 1.5 USD RP2040 could do the entire Apollo mission.

Comment: @winny Great - I shall abide by this principle going forward . Thank you

Comment: That, and promise to always use sufficient decoupling capacitors for all your circuits and solid ground plane!

Comment: @fKelectronicR please don't ask `is it possible to make?` ... that question has a `yes` answer almost always, so it is not very useful ... please ask `how to make?` to get a useful answer

Comment: What is easy and cost effective to you?  Sure, you can use one or two 14- or 16-pin logic chips to do this, and half a dozen resistors and capacitors.  But -- you've now used up enough board space for several 6- or 8-pin microcontrollers.

Comment: This question is asked with some regularity. Please look at all the previous ones :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plenty of options!

An OR IC, any 74x32 in this configuration:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fICdqH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Or if you want it even more discreet, the classic BJT thyristor configuration, borrowed from here: [Replace transistor-latch with thyristor: is my circuit correct?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/631440/replace-transistor-latch-with-thyristor-is-my-circuit-correct)

[image]

Suggestion by Chris Knudsen, latching relay:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKuICA.png)</sup>

Comment: ...and the classic start-stop control switch using latching mechanical relays, or relay feedback.

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen Classic! I'll add it.

Comment: @winny Great thanks for you answer. The schematic above the "BJT thyristor configuration" has two switch. A trigger and reset. Is it possible to achieve the same outcome with only one switch. Thanks

Comment: @fKelectronicR If you skip the reset, it will stay latched until you power it down.

Comment: Frankly, I don't see how that AND gate circuit is going to work. Once the output is low, it stays low regardless of the input. The question asked for a push-on/push-off function. Furthermore, you have not included circuitry to set it HI on power-up, so it's perfectly possible that it will turn on LOW, and stay there no matter what you do.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Sorry, OR I mean. I’ll edit it.

Comment: OK, so how is the OR circuit supposed to toggle? :^)

Comment: @Transistor It doesn’t. Title says latch.

Comment: @winny - The text says, " I would like to add a push switch which when pressed once will turn the circuit on, then when pressed again will turn the circuit off."

Comment: @winny - Hi, None of your options satisfy the OP's requirement of a 'Push-to-on / push-to-off' arrangement, using a single push button switch.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing as simple as a 'self-locking, push-on / push-off switch'.

[image]